# Multiple/Sub queries with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I just started with Codeigniter and this is driving me nuts. I have a query that determines whether a user has bought any programs. I then have to use that program's type category to run and determine how many times he or she has recorded a query in another table. Sorry for the confusion but the code hopefully makes sense.

I'm having problem returning the two arrays from my Model to my Controller to onto the view obviously.

```
function specificPrograms() {
$specific_sql = $this->db->query("SELECT program,created FROM  `assessment`  WHERE uid = $this->uid");
if($specific_sql->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach ($specific_sql->result() as $specific) {        
$data[] = $specific;
$this->type = $specific->program;   
}
return $data;
}   

$sub_sql = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM othertable WHERE user_id_fk = $this->uid and type = '$this->type'");
if($sub_sql->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach ($sub_sql->result() as $otherp) {       
$data[] = $otherp;
}
return $data;
}

}
```

Then in my Controller I have,

```
$data['specific'] = $this->user_model->specificPrograms();
$data['otherp'] = $this->user_model->specificPrograms();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you describe more what your expectations are with the code? What do you expect `$data['specific']` and `$data['otherp']` to be set to after this runs? What are they set to now?

Comment: Sure, basically. Let's say that a user has purchase 3 separate programs and for each program, he or she has used it a certain number of times, this number would be a recorded as the id from othertable. So for example, Bob has bought product 1, product 2, and product 3. I need to know the 'program' that Bob purchased along with how many id's have been recorded in the othertable that correspond with the product or type. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Sorry, let's try a better example: Bob has purchased 3 different workouts: baseball, basketball and football workouts. For each has has done a certain number of workouts that will be recorded and using num-rows returned by the second sql query. I need the sport (basketball, football, baseball...) along with the number of workouts Bob has done for each sport (count id).

Comment: Alright, that's quite different than I expected from the question, so see if I'm on the right track...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments above, I suggest one query which returns the results you need. The result set of this will look like this:

```
+----------+------------+------+
| program  | created    | uses |
+----------+------------+------+
| football | 2001-01-01 | 12   |
+----------+------------+------+
| baseball | 2007-01-01 | 21   |
+----------+------------+------+


SELECT 
  assessment.program, 
  assessment.created, 
  count(othertable.user_id) as uses
FROM  assessment
JOIN othertable 
  ON othertable.user_id_fk = assessment.uid
  AND othertable.type = assessment.program
WHERE assessment.uid = $this->uid
GROUP BY assessment.program

... model ...

function specificPrograms() {
  $results = $this->db->query($sql_from_above);
  if($specific_sql->num_rows() > 0) {
  foreach ($specific_sql->result() as $program_data) {        
    $data[] = $program_data;
  }
  return $data;
}

... meanwhile in controller ...


$programs_used = $this->user_model->specificPrograms();
foreach($programs_used as $program_use_data) {
  // On first iteration, this is true:
  // $program_use_data['program'] == "football"
  // $program_use_date['uses'] == 12
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I'm getting the error, 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to return $data from the model function :-/ fixed.